# PAW Server/BeanShell on Android and ADB

Tags: android, apk, adb, beanshell

I have a need to install APK's remotely and want to use PAW Server.  I know PAW Server in itself can't install APK's directly, but I could enable ADB on the devices and use PAW Server's BeanShell scripting to execute adb install.  Unfortunately I'm a BeanShell n00b and there's not really any documentation on using BeanShell and ADB together.  Does anyone know if this is possible and how I might call ADB from BeanShell?

edit for clarification: The device will be at another physical location which I will have VPN access to, so I can address the tablet by IP but not by USB.  That's why I need PAW Server or something like it and not just the standard ADB from PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to adb - you don't need anything else to install packages. You could either use `adb install <apk>` or if the package file is downloaded to the device already - `adb shell pm install <apk>` command

Comment: The device will be at another physical location which I will have VPN access to, so I can address the tablet by IP but not by USB.  That's why I need PAW Server or something like it.

Comment: As long as you have adb access which you said you could get - you can run the commands I suggested. No matter which media (ethernet/wifi/usb/etc) adb runs over.

Comment: Yes, I have access to ADB, but not the USB port.  They also won't be connected to PC's at any time, just constantly plugged into a wall outlet and running in sort of a kiosk-mode.  That rules out forwarding the ADB server from a connected PC.  The devices won't be rooted so ADB over WIFI won't work.  This basically needs to be a direct connection from my PC to the tablet's IP.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you mean by "having access to ADB"? Because it seems that you don't have it. To read what adb is go to http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: I know what ADB means, the devices will be powered on and connected to WIFI but not connected to a PC.  ADB is enabled on the devices, so runs only to USB unless a person roots the device, which is not an option.  The point is to update non-market apps from a remote location.  This could be accomplished if all devices were connected to a PC that forwarded ADB over TCP, but that too is not an option.  Rephrasing what I mean, I have ADB running but I have no method of gaining access to its location, hence the thought to write a plugin for PAW that allows upload of APK's then adb install them.